How to pass in string parameter in python-bdd test
I am trying to write a very simple test using pytest and pytest-bdd. The test runs OK if none of the step definitions have any parameters. However, I cannot seem to get to work the simple passing in of a single string parameter.
Here is my step:
Given the current account balance is "zero"

Here is the step definition:
@given("the current account balance is {arg}")
def current_account_initial_balance(amount):
    print(amount)

When I run the test, then this is the output (somewhat edited for clarity):
============================================================= test session starts ============================================================== 
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0rootdir: C:\pythonplugins: bdd-8.0.0
collected 1 item

TestBankTransactions.py F

=========================================================== short test summary info ============================================================ 
FAILED TestBankTransactions.py::test_deposit_into_account - pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: Given "the current account balance is "zero"". Line 6 in sc... 
============================================================== 1 failed in 0.02s ===============================================================

I have tried all sorts of googling and different combinations of "' and "" but nothing has worked.

In the traditional spirit of answering one's own question - I found that the following worked:
@given(parsers.parse("the current account balance is {amount}"))
def current_account_initial_balance(amount):
    print(amount)

This is with parsers imported at the top of the Python file:
import scenarios, scenario, given, when, then, parsers

Hope this helps someone! Martin
